# Proper Procedure to create a n-tier Website in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the correct procedure to create an n-tier Website in ASP.NET?  Can this be done without setting up a server farm, and how would you be able to test it?  Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally support the example specified by Layered Architecture sample on codeplex

It can be downloaded from the following location:

http://layersample.codeplex.com/

It comes with a sample application which should outline and explain good patterns and practices for a fictional company.

You could use this as a guide when developing an n-tier architecture application. If you need a greater understanding of what n-tier actually is you could look at wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

With regards to requiring a server farm for hosting an n-tier application; this is not a requirement. The idea behind an n-tier application is creating a flexible and scalabale application. Initially if the application is not resource intensive it is possible to group all the tiers on the same server. As the application becomes more resource intensive and requested the tiers can and should be scaled out across multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

A tier does not necessarily involve having a server farm.

Below image shows a 3 tier architecture with only one server in both Tier 2 and Tier 3.

[image]

However, in general, there is sometimes a lot of confusion in the whole Tier / Layer terminology.

An excellent post on Layers v/s Tiers is [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2005/07/23/129745.aspx).

Also Rockford Lhotka's [post](http://www.lhotka.net/WeBlog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=efa88d0a-2388-4909-bee1-c9bddb6e9868) referenced in this article is also an excellent resource.